# Direct Variation, Divide by Zero

Tags: linear-algebra

How does direct variation work with x/y = k when at the origin, does the point there simply not exist or what?

Comment: Instead of the equation $\frac{x}{y}=k$, it is often defined instead as $x=yk$  (or equivalently as $y=xn$).  Defining it with a fraction does cause a problem, as you point out, when looking at the origin, however when the relationship is defined without fractions, there is absolutely no ambiguity.

Comment: ok, that clears it up, I had seen it as y=kx or y/x=k, my pre calc teacher uses the latter and I was confused for a moment as he said that all direct variation equations must go through the origin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indeed. You have a straight line of varying slope (depending on which value you choose for $k$).

When drawing the line, you add an open circle at $(0,0)$ to indicate that that point is not included.

[image: no origin]